# How can I combine a few regular expressions into one?

Tags: xpath

Good afternoon,

I have 3 following regular expressions which I need to combine into one:

- `//*[local-name()!="shipping-methoc"][*[local-name()="online-flag"]="true"]/*[local-name()!="description"]`
- `//*[local-name()!="shipping-methoc"][*[local-name()="online-flag"]="true"]/*[local-name()!="title"]`
- `//*[local-name()!="shipping-methoc"][*[local-name()="online-flag"]="true"]/*[local-name()!="flag"]`

How can I do this?
All the best
Wojciech

Comment: These are XPath expressions, not regexps. Please retag the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

- Starting an XPath expression with `//` means that the engine will search through every element in the document.  This is extremely inefficient.
- The best way to formulate an XPath expression can depend on where you're using it.  Is this in a template match?  Is this in a select statement?  Is this somewhere else?  What other context can you give us?
- Another factor is which version of XSLT / XPath you are using.  Some features available in XLST v2.0 and later can allow for shorter expressions.

As you apparently realized, these three lines have nearly identical XPath expressions, where the only difference is the last condition on the end.  With minimal changes to your sample code, we could combine those three different last conditions into one single expression.  This should work even in XSLT 1.

- `//*[local-name()!='shipping-methoc'][*[local-name()='online-flag']='true']/*[local-name()!='description' and local-name()!='title' and local-name()!='flag']`

If you can use XSLT 2 or newer, you gain access to additional options for both positive and negative matches.

I'm guessing from your use of `local-name()` that you don't care about namespace prefixes.  For positive matches, you can use `*:` as the prefix for "any namespace".

- `//*[local-name()!='shipping-methoc'][*:online-flag='true']/*[local-name()!='description' and local-name()!='title' and local-name()!='flag']`

You can also use the `except` keyword as an additional option for negative matches.

- `//(* except *:shipping-methoc)[*:online-flag='true']/(* except (*:description | *:title | *:flag))`